# Are there reasons to not type cast pointers (C)?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, microcontroller

I'm fairly new to C, feel free to educate...

I am working with a function that is expecting a pointer to a char array as an input. It is quite cumbersome to individually set each element of the array before its call. I have found a couple of alternatives that appear to work, but am concerned that I am stepping into a trap. Below are a couple of options.

Option 1:

```
 unsigned char DataToPass[8];
 uint64_t *IntPtr = (uint64_t *)DataToPass;
   ...
 *IntPtr = 0x1122334455667788;
 FunctionCall(DataToPass);
```

Option 2:

```
unsigned char DataToPass[8];
uint64_t IntData;
...
iDataToPass = 0x1122334455667788;
memcpy(DataToPass, &IntData, sizeof(IntData);
FunctionCall(DataToPass);
```

Comment: Your code is dependent on whether the CPU is big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: @Barmar that is really important if the intention is to set each element in the array.

Comment: What is wrong with an initializer list?

Comment: This also assumes that a uint64_t is the same size as 8 chars. It is mostly, but there are weird exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Example 1 may cause undefined behaviour due to alignment violation. Also it causes UB by violating the strict aliasing rule.

Example 2 does not cause UB, however it has implementation-defined result. `DataToPass[0]` would be `0x88` on common systems, but `0x11` and `0x55` also exist, and in fact anything is possible.

My advice would be to write code that clearly expresses your intent:

```
unsigned char DataToPass[8] = { 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88 };
```

It'll take you, what , 10 seconds to type but will save a lot of pain.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit dirty but you could use a union.

```
union Data
{
   char c [8];
   uint64_t i;
};

void Func (char *data);

void test ()
{
  Data d;
  d.i = 0x1122334455667788;
  Func (d.c);
}
```

I think that'd work. Doesn't get around endian problems though.

(I feel I need to have a really thorough wash now)

Comment: This is perfectly legitimate in modern C standards. You *do* however need to declare `union Data d;` or typedef `Data`.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples are fine - with one caveat. You need to ensure that `DataToPass` is correctly aligned for your system in order for Option 1 to work correctly. Option 2 is fine as is.  If you're really looking to type less, why not:

```
uint64_t IntData = 0x1122334455667788;
FunctionCall((unsigned char *)&IntData);
```

As @Barmar mentions in his comment, endianness of your system will play a role here as well.

Comment: The first example is not fine

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Could you elaborate?

Comment: The buffer may not be correctly aligned for `uint64_t`. Also it violates the strict aliasing rule (char may not be aliased as uint64_t).

Comment: @CarlNorum It is the type of the lvalue doing the access which has the "special cases", and `uint64_t` is not a special case.